# Convert NGVD 1929 to NAVD 1988?

Tags: elevation, datum

My root issue is that I have elevation values in NGVD 1929 that need to be related to a DEM which has elevation values in NAVD 1988.

Is there a way that I can convert elevation from one data to another en masse?

I have searched online for a solution but so far have only come up with an app that will give you the difference between the two elevations at a single point.

Answer (score 3):

NOAA distributes an application called [VDatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/) which will do vertical datum transformations.  VDatum is free and cross platform but it is a Java application so you will need to install Java.  VDatum accepts an [ASCII text](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide.html#step31) file so you can do the transformations in bulk.  You will need to populate your attribute table with X, Y, and Z values and then export the table to ASCII before feeding it into VDatum.

The links above point to the VDatum download page and the ASCII instruction help page.